# Is there any way to keep the previous value when communication is lost in the C# EasyModub package?

Tags: c#, communication, modbus

Use the EasyModbus package on .Net.

Modbus Client Serial RTU

Communication is sometimes lost, and all values are zero.
Is there no option to keep the previous value when communication is lost?

[image]

I want to keep the value before it disconnects when the communication is momentarily disconnected.